# Convert HTML to PDF in JAVA without using any librarys

Tags: java, html, pdf, data-conversion

So my problem is that we are trying to take a chunk of HTML code and, using java, create a PDF file from it for a customer to view. We don't want to make the customer install any third party converters, or use any of the java libraries (like Itext). Is this possible? The easier the solution the better. Maintaining format is a plus but not necessary.

Comment: *The easier the solution the better.* use third party libraries.

Comment: Create own library is only option if you don't like to use any 3rd party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 3rd party library then wrap it up inside your distribution process so that the customer never sees it.

For example use a proper installer to install your program, there are lots of easy-to-use programs to generate installers for you.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution is only client side Javascript and then uses external server to receive that, format it and return it. See http//www.xportability. com/XEPOnline/FOTestSuite.html for early example. The client side will be made available through github soon. The server side is a commercial solution with options for you or us to host. Or you could build your own as it works with XSL FO.